# Zend Form old password verification

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

How can i check if a specific record exists with Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists?

Here is my code, i want  to match old password before user changes it

```
 $oldpassexist = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
            'table' => 'user',
            'field' => 'password',
                /** check if password matches
                 *  WHERE user_id = Auth::getuser()->id AND password = md5(THIS FIELD ENTRY) 
                 */
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another where clause is pretty easy. `Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists` allows you to modify the `Zend_Db_Select` object that it uses internally. So you could write:

```
$oldpassexist = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
        'table' => 'user',
        'field' => 'password',
    ));

// reset the where clause used by Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists
$oldpassexist->getSelect()->reset('where');

// set user_id and password. :value is a named parameter that will be 
// substituted by the value passed to the isValid method
$oldpassexist->getSelect()->where('user_id = ?', Auth::getuser()->id);
$oldpassexist->getSelect()->where('password = MD5(:value)');
```

Which will query both the password as hashed MD5 as well as the user_id field. However, I think this solution is not really elegant. I would probably write my own Validator for this. In any case you should write thorough test cases to detect if the behavior of `Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists` changes one day.

Comment: Thank you! Worked very nice!

Comment: When I tried this solution I received error "Invalid bind-variable name ':value'". After I changed :value to ?, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on another site :))

http://husseycoding.blogspot.fr/2011/07/creating-custom-zend-form-validator.html

Comment: You should include code relevant to answering the question in your answer. Just linking to another site doesnt help the community.